# pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43

Tags: r, pdf, markdown, knitr, pandoc

I encountered the below message when compiling a markdown script in two different circumstances. This is the general error message:

> ! Missing $ inserted.
>    
>                   $ l.90 2.2211\times
>
> pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF Error: pandoc document conversion
>   failed with error 43 In addition: Warning message: running command
>   '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS
>   test.utf8.md --to latex --from
>   markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash
>   --output test.pdf --template "C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-33~1.1\library\RMARKD~1\rmd\latex\DEFAUL~3.TEX"
>   --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in"' had status 43 
>   Execution halted

Here is markdown code to reproduce the message:

````
---
title: "test"
author: "AB"
date: "29 November 2016"
output: pdf_document
---
```{r, message = FALSE, echo = FALSE}

y <- 22211
```

`r sum(y)`
````

It seems to have to do with the integer that is supposed to be written in the markdown file. I encountered another instance, where the same error occured after performing a statistical test that gave out a test statistic with several decimal places. Even when telling markdown to round to 3 digits, the problem occurs when trying to knit.

The following solves the issue:

```
$`r sum(y)`$
```

However, for large markdown documents it is difficult to find the places responsible for these errors. The error message does not point to the exact place.

Is there a better way to solve this error?